# LuaJ wrong return type conversion

Tags: types, lua, luaj, multiple-return-values

I have the following code, which does not work as I expected, using LuaJ.

```
/* imports ommited */
public class LuaTest {

public static String name = "script";
public static String script =
    "function numbers()"
    + "   return 200, 100"
    + "   end "
    + "object = obj:new() " 
    + "x = numbers() " 
    + "print(x)" 
    + "print(\"x type = \" .. type(x))" 
    + "z = object:numbers()" 
    + "print(z)" 
    + "print(\"z type = \" .. type(z))";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    LuaValue myObject = CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(new MyClass());
    Globals globals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
    globals.set("obj", myObject);
    LuaValue chunk = globals.load(script);
    chunk.call();
}
}

public class MyClass {

public VarArgFunction numbers() {
    return new MultiValueReturn(LuaValue.valueOf(200), LuaValue.valueOf(100));
}

public class MultiValueReturn extends VarArgFunction {
    private LuaValue[] args;

    public MultiValueReturn(LuaValue p1, LuaValue p2) {
        this.args = new LuaValue[2];
        this.args[0] = p1;
        this.args[1] = p2;
    }

    @Override
    public LuaValue arg(int i) {
        if (i <= this.args.length) {
            return args[i - 1];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Notice that my Lua script calls two different functions called "numbers", one from a coerced object, and other in native Lua. Both should behave the same way returning two values, from which, only the first is used.

The execution output is this:

```
200
x type = number
200
z type = function
```

But I expected it to be something like this:

```
200
x type = number
200
z type = number
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your class is getting coerced, but the multiple return values are challenging.

Make 'number' a field of type VarArgFunction and implement VarArgFunction.invoke() instead.

Then lua's *object.numbers* maps to the value of Java's *MyClass.numbers*, which is a VarArgFunction, and can therefor be called with multiple arguments and return multiple return values.

```java
public class LuaTest {

    public static String name = "script";
    public static String script =
        "function numbers()"
        + "   return 200, 100"
        + "   end "
        + "object = obj:new() " 
        + "x = numbers() " 
        + "print(x)" 
        + "print(\"x type = \" .. type(x))" 
        + "z = object:numbers()" 
        + "print(z)" 
        + "print(\"z type = \" .. type(z))";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LuaValue myObject = CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(new MyClass());
        Globals globals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
        globals.set("obj", myObject);
        LuaValue chunk = globals.load(script);
        chunk.call();
    }

    public static class MyClass {

        public VarArgFunction numbers = new VarArgFunction() {
            @Override
            public Varargs invoke(Varargs args) {
                return varargsOf(valueOf(200), valueOf(100));
            }
        };
    }
}
```